# Clear 2 Textfield in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a simple HTML code to clear 2 textboxes once the Clear Text button is clicked. Now it only clears 1 text field instead of 2.
How can I make it so that it clears both at the same time?

```
<script>
        function swapValues() {
            var tmp = document.getElementById("a").value;
            document.getElementById("a").value = document.getElementById("b").value;
            document.getElementById("b").value = tmp;
        }
        function clear() {
            var clearA = document.getElementById('a').value = '';
            var clearB = document.getElementById('b').value = '';

            if (clearA != " " && clearB != " "){
                document.getElementById('myInput').value = ''
            }
        }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>

<input type="text" id="a" value="John" /><br><br>
<input type="text" id="b" value="Lee" /><br><br>

<input type="button" id="go" onclick="swapValues()" value="Swap">

<button onclick="document.getElementById('a').value = ''">Clear Text</button>
```

Comment: Should the values be "John" and "Lee" per default, or are they just there while testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after correcting the errors in your code, the "clear()" function will not run. Clear is not a saved keyword. But most likely there is a conflict with [document.clear();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear). Therefore, it is necessary to change the name of this function to work correctly.

**Example:**

```js
function swapValues() {
    var tmp = document.getElementById("a").value;
    document.getElementById("a").value = document.getElementById("b").value;
    document.getElementById("b").value = tmp;
}

function clearValue() {
    var clearA = document.getElementById('a');
    var clearB = document.getElementById('b');

    clearA.value = '';
    clearB.value = '';

    if (clearA.value != '' && clearB.value != '') {
        console.log('some action');
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="a" value="John" /><br><br>
<input type="text" id="b" value="Lee" /><br><br>

<input type="button" id="go" onclick="swapValues()" value="Swap">

<button onclick="clearValue()">Clear Text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate both clear actions with `;`:

```
   onclick="document.getElementById('a').value = ''; document.getElementById('b').value = ''; "
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are assigning the none output to another variable?

```
function clear() {
            document.getElementById('a').value = '';
            document.getElementById('b').value = '';

            if (document.getElementById('a').value != " " && document.getElementById('b').value != " "){
                document.getElementById('myInput').value = ''
            }
        }
```

And set `onClick` to call `clear()`:

```
<button onclick="clear();">Clear Text</button>
```